# Filtered google cast device scan yields nothing (iOS)

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

If I launch the device scanner without a filter the chromecast device is located & everything is well.

If I launch the device scanner filtered for my app, my understanding is that the chromecast device running the app should be detected. But the device scan yields nothing (or at least the deviceDidComeOnline delegate method is never called).

At the time of the test my receiver is up and running on the TV (the receiver app supports the standard media channel plus another ad-hoc channel with the namespace `urn:x-cast:com.mycompany.mychannel`)

What am I doing wrong?

```
    // _filteredScanner and _filter are both 'strong' attributes of the class
    - (id) init {
      self = [super init];
      if (self != nil) {
        _filteredScanner = [[GCKDeviceScanner alloc] init] ;
        GCKFilterCriteria *myappRunningCriteria = [GCKFilterCriteria         criteriaForRunningApplicationWithID:nil supportedNamespaces:@[@"urn:x-cast:com.mycompany.mychannel", @"urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media"]];
        _filter = [[GCKDeviceFilter alloc] initWithDeviceScanner: _filteredScanner criteria: myappRunningCriteria] ;
        [_filter addDeviceFilterListener:self];
        [_filteredScanner startScan] ;
      }
      return self ;
    }


    #pragma mark - GCKDeviceFilterListener
    - (void)deviceDidComeOnline:(GCKDevice *)device forDeviceFilter: (GCKDeviceFilter*)filter {
      NSLog(@"OK Device scanner filter found new device: %@", device.friendlyName);
    }

    - (void)deviceDidGoOffline:(GCKDevice *)device forDeviceFilter: (GCKDeviceFilter*) filter{
      NSLog(@"OK Device scanner filter reported device offline: %@", device.friendlyName);
    }
```

Comment: I presume your app is not published yet? If that is the case, is your device configured for your unpublished app on the Cast Developer Console?

Comment: @AliNaddaf Yes the device is registered for development in the Cast Developer Console (I can find the device when not using a filter, create my custom channel, communicate with the receiver etc...)

Comment: If you try just using the com.google.cast.media URN does it appear in the filter callbacks then? (Similarly, does it appear if just your own)?

Comment: @IanBarber I tried with both channel namespaces, just my ad-hoc one and just the media channel, all without success

Comment: Can you try passing an application ID rather than nil, and see if that triggers? I appreciate the docs say that can be nil!

Comment: @IanBarber yes, I tried passing the applicationId as well instead of nil - same result unfortunately. If that matters I am using iOS8 & GoogleCastFramework-2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was a bug in the google Cast iOS SDK v2.3.0 that was just fixed in v2.4.0 (see the [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=373))